# how to compare successive candles based on an accurate highs and lows

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

i want to compare each successive two candles as follows :

- get green arrow when the highest price of candle is bigger than the highest of previous candle
- get yellow arrow when the lowest price of candle is lower than the lowest price of previous candle
- get purple arrow when both lowest and highest price of candle is smaller than previous candle's lowest and highest price
- get red candle when both lowest and highest price of candle is bigger than previous candle's lowest and highest price

i did it ,but this script is giving me errors on the conditions (makes the green purple and so on) ,  and i don't know why !

```
//@version=5
indicator("Arrows Based on Price Movement", overlay=true)

prevHigh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", high[1])
prevLow = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", low[1])

currentHigh = high
currentLow = low

isGreenArrow = currentHigh > prevHigh and currentLow > prevLow
isYellowArrow = currentLow < prevLow and currentHigh < prevHigh
isPurpleArrow = currentHigh <= prevHigh and currentLow >= prevLow
isRedArrow = currentHigh > prevHigh and currentLow < prevLow

arrowColor = isGreenArrow ? color.green : isYellowArrow ? color.yellow : isPurpleArrow ? color.purple : color.red

plotarrow(series=isGreenArrow ? low - (currentHigh - prevHigh) * 0.2 : na, title="Green Arrow", colorup=arrowColor, colordown=arrowColor, offset=-1)
plotarrow(series=isYellowArrow ? low - (prevLow - currentLow) * 0.2 : na, title="Yellow Arrow", colorup=arrowColor, colordown=arrowColor, offset=-1)
plotarrow(series=isPurpleArrow ? low - ((currentHigh + currentLow) / 2 - (prevHigh + prevLow) / 2) * 0.2 : na, title="Purple Arrow", colorup=arrowColor, colordown=arrowColor, offset=-1)
plotarrow(series=isRedArrow ? low - (currentHigh - currentLow) * 0.2 : na, title="Red Arrow", colorup=arrowColor, colordown=arrowColor, offset=-1)
```